# Why does Pynt need DinD to run in GitLab CI/CD

Tags: docker, postman, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-in-docker

I need to run Pynt to automate security tests for APIs i have, I've a collection and an environment and it all works perfectly fine through Postman, now i want to run it on GitLab CI/CD using Newman; I've built a docker image to include python (for Pynt), npm (for Newman) and DinD since Pynt apparently needs it.

Using this set up i get an error that the docker daemon needs privileged access which has some security risks that concern me, my question is why does Pynt need the DinD and docker daemon environment?

I've tried different set-ups like using DinD in a custom docker image, i tried using it with "service:" but i get the same output in the runner.

Here's what I get in gitlab runner: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NCxx.png) , My gitlab yml file is very simple, it just installs dependencies for newman and pynt and runs the four script commands you see in the image.

Comment: Why ask here and not pynt support or developers? Which documentation did your searched for and read?

Comment: @KamilCuk I did my search through their documentation and i found nothing that explains the need or usage of DinD.

Comment: can you share the error?

Comment: did u tryin to ask in the community of Pynt? they answer very quick
https://pynt-community.slack.com

Answer (score 1):

Having docker available is a [documented prerequisite](https://docs.pynt.io/documentation/onboarding/prerequisites) to using `pynt`. This is because the `pynt` CLI invokes `docker` commands to perform its function. In relevant part, the documentation states:

> Please note that the Pynt solution is based on docker and requires access to the local host [...]
> Ensure the **Docker engine** is available and running on your machine

The [CI/CD documentation for pynt](https://docs.pynt.io/documentation/onboarding/getting-started/pynt-on-ci-cd) describes the GitLab CI configuration to achieve this assuming you are either using GitLab.com shared runners or a self-hosted docker-based executor using docker-in-docker.

There's probably more than one configuration that will let you do this in GitLab CI, but in any case, you'll need to make sure that you have the ability to run `docker` commands in your GitLab CI jobs to be able to use `pynt`.

Since you're getting an error, this is because you are using a self-hosted runner that is not [configured for use with docker-in-docker](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker). In which case, you will need to configure this to use `docker` (and by extension to use `pynt`) in your jobs. If your runner is configured to use docker using the [socket binding method](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-the-docker-executor-with-docker-socket-binding) just remove the `services:` section from the provided example because it won't be needed in that scenario.

Comment: I have no control nor access to the GitLab runners in my project (i can ask for help but it takes time). Is there any way to confirm that the runner i have does in-fact allow docker commands to run ?
Also i added an image of the gitlab runner output, please take a look at it.

Comment: You can try just running `docker info` in a job. If the command works, then you should be OK to use `pynt` otherwise, you need help from the administrator of your runner @HamzaMoghrabi

Comment: I see, it is giving me "docker is not running" so it seems we need to figure it out from the project settings.

Answer (score 0):

Pynt does not need dind. It does need docker available as it executes docker commands.

Now the docker cli is not docker - it just talks using the docker API to an instance of docker engine. Docker engine does stuff like actually running containers. And herein lies the problem - you can run docker-engine in a container - using docker:dind. But docker is a bit of a trick - it doesn't actually run anything - it simply sets up linux kernel objects to run an isolated linux process and hands it off to linux to run.

And here we return to the problem - the docker:dind container is just that - a usermode process that needs an OS to actually run its containers. So it literally cannot do anything without being given permission to create cgroups and network namespaces on the host. And that means it needs privileged access to the host.

There is an alternative - you already have an instance of docker on the host - you can mount /var/run/docker.sock into the gitlab runner and into any containers and then their docker cli will find and call that docker instance.
This is, arguably less secure as these containers now have access to the same docker instance that hosts the runner itself. If runners go beyond simple docker build, docker push etc. actions, they could, for example, kill containers, or start compose stacks that will outlive any job as they are owned by the host docker. A transient docker:dind instance will not give access to the host and any long lived containers will be shut down when it is closed.

---

Its worth noting that there is a project to run the docker daemon rootless, and along with that, there is a docker:dind-rootless container. Currently the [privileged flag is still required](https://github.com/docker-library/docker/issues/291)

Comment: I have more understanding about docker and docker engine from your answer, so basically Pynt needs to execute docker commands and for that it needs a docker engine to run them and there's no way around that, my understanding is correct ?

Comment: Not a user pf pynt, but from the docs, that seems to be the gist of it, yes.